STM32F401 Issue with interrupt request
I have a nucleo board, and on it I have a button. The button is connected to the pin C13 and upon pressing it, I am supposed to stop my PWM signal from progressing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Here is the code for defining the interrupt and its behaviour.
void INTERRUPT_CONFIG(){

    RCC->APB2ENR|=RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;
    SYSCFG->EXTICR[2]|=(0x2<<SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI1_Pos);
    EXTI->IMR|=(0x1<<EXTI_IMR_MR1_Pos);
    EXTI->RTSR|=(0x1<<EXTI_RTSR_TR13_Pos);
    EXTI->FTSR|=(0x0<<EXTI_FTSR_TR13_Pos);
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI1_IRQn,1);
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI1_IRQn);


}
bool flag=false;
void EXTI1_IRQHandler(){
    if(EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR13_Pos){
        EXTI->PR|=(0x0<<EXTI_PR_PR13_Pos);
        flag=!flag;
    }
}

... and here is the main function:
int main(void)
{
  TIM2_INIT();
  //button is pc13
  INTERRUPT_CONFIG();
     EXTI1_IRQHandler();
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOCEN;
    GPIOC->MODER |= ( 0x0 << GPIO_MODER_MODE13_Pos);
    GPIOC->PUPDR |= ( 0x1 << GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD13_Pos);//defining the Pin c13

  while (1)
  {
      if(flag==true){
          TIM2->CR1&=~(TIM_CR1_CEN);
      }
      else{
      int x;
          for(x=0; x<500; x=x+1)
          {
            TIM2->CCR1=x;
            delayFunct(1);
          }
          for(x=500; x>0; x=x-1)
          {
              TIM2->CCR1=x;
              delayFunct(1);
  }
}

I know the question is a bit verbose, but still would appreciate some help. Thank you guys in advance.
So far I have messed with the contents of the EXTI register values, but to no avail

Separate the issues: detecting the button, and stopping the PWM. BTW, it is commonly a bad idea to use (edge) interrupts with buttons, as button bounce. -- Oh, and what specific question do you have?

non volatile does not help


if(EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR13_Pos) is wrong, the bit mask for pin13 should be 0x01 << EXTI_PR_PR13_Pos.  2) why are you calling EXTI1_IRQHandler(); in the main()? 3) don't know what is your design logic, you either don't need the flag at all (stop the timer permanently) or you forgot to reset the flag in the main(), and 4) in the latter case, the flag need to be declared as volatile.


Thanks @hcheung and everyone, I'll implement the changes today and see how it checks out, I'll keep you updated

One more thing, I think EXT1->PR register is typically write 1 to clear the interrupt flag, so it should be EXTI->PR |= (1<<EXTI_PR_PR13_Pos);, you should check the Reference Manual to confirm it.

@hcheung I fixed the button interrupt by adding NVIC_SetVector(EXTI15_10_IRQn, EXTI15_10_IRQn); and it made it work, but now my button only works only 1 time, ie I cannot stop and start my PWM, only stop it, trying to find a solution to that now

That was what I referred to the point 3 in my comment. You set the flag in the interrupt, but there is no where you reset the flag and if you look at the code logic, it disable the timer permanently when the flag is set.

To preface this, some of the things have been changed rather extensively due to my mentors advice, such as the logic in the IRQ, usage of unions, hope you
can still understand the code
void Interrupt_Init(void){
EXTI15_10_Init(); 
NVIC->IP[EXTI15_10_IRQn] =  (1 << 4);    
NVIC->ISER[40 >> 5] |= (1 << (40 % 32)); 
}

union InterruptFlag {
struct {
   volatile bool flag: 1; // Just one bit for our flag
   volatile bool press: 1;
} bits_access;
uint32_t reg; // We'll use this for byte access
};
volatile union InterruptFlag flag = { .bits_access.flag = 0 }; // 
Initialize 
to 0
volatile uint16_t pressTime;
volatile bool lastButtonPress=0;
volatile bool buttonPress=1;

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler(void){
flag.bits_access.flag = !flag.bits_access.flag;
EXTI->PR |= (1<<13);  // Clear PR to re-enable EXTI interrupt

}

void clearIR(void){
flag.bits_access.flag = 0;
buttonPress=0;

}

and now for the new contents of the main function, the definition of the functions is the same, it's just the while loop that has changed;
while (1)
{
  int x;
      for(x=0; x<500; x++)
      {
          if(flag.bits_access.flag== 1){
                    x=x-1;
                    TIM2->CCR1=x;
              }
          else{
                    TIM2->CCR1=x;
                    delayTRIP(1);
          }}

      for(x=500; x>0; x--)
      {
          if(flag.bits_access.flag== 1){
                      x=x+1;
                      TIM2->CCR1=x;
                          }
          else{
                      TIM2->CCR1=x;
                      delayTRIP(1);
      }

  }
 }}

